# Cohen’s “Number Theory” Series

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I’ve seen one or two things about this book series but not much. What do you think of them?I’d like to really start digging into number theory and am looking for a good book to get into. Would these two books be a good place to start?

I’ve read a bit about p-adics and am currently studying commutative algebra and modules, measure theory, basic algebraic topology, and complex analysis. I have previously studied groups, rings, linear algebra over fields, Galois theory, general topology, R^1 analysis, metric spaces, some category theory, and a bit of representation theory of finite groups.

Thank you!

Comment: I haven't read either of them.  But if you know some commutative algebra and know something about the p-adics, you could try learning algebraic number theory (Lang, Milne, or Neukirch).  Or with your complex analysis background you can learn about modular forms (Diamond & Shurman).

Comment: Could you please highlight some of the differences between Lang and Neukrich?

Comment: And +1 for Diamond and Shurman! It looks very interesting.

Comment: Lang sticks to the facts and doesn't motivate the material as much as Neukirch.  And he's much more of an analyst.

Comment: Interesting. I’ll take a look at both.